# Does we have any emoji plugin which gives code like &#128563; after click on image

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, emoji

I have searched lots of jquery emoji plugins but they returned code like :smiley: which is not used browser push notification.
then i tried code like 😳 which displays the smiley icon in notification.

Does anyone know converter or emoji plugin which does this

Comment: Emoji are just Unicode characters. No plugins should be needed to display them. If you're having problems getting them to work, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i dont know whether i am on right way or wrong but I have used https://github.com/diy/jquery-emojiarea plugin for emojis which generate code like :smile: , :angry: which later gets converted to [] in preview as well as in FCM notification.

Comment: @Frank i dont know whether i am on right way or wrong but I have used https://github.com/diy/jquery-emojiarea plugin for emojis which generate code like :smile: , :angry: which later gets converted to [] in preview as well as in FCM notification, but after searching i found only code like  `code` &#128563; `code` which actually display the icon, so i have manually convert shortcodes(:smile:) to hex code.But now its only working for black and white icons only.If i use hexcode of colored icon say &#128102; then Notification displays [].How we can display coloured images in FCM notification?

Comment: Codes like :smile: are not emoji. They're just codes that apps use to make it easier for their users to input emoji, if their device doesn't have an emoji keyboard. It sounds like the device you target doesn't support the &#128102; emoji (yet), or you have a bug in your conversion code. It will be impossible to help further without seeing the minimal code/conditions that are needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks for the help.It was the code that was not supported in browser.